# Deploying Android Wearable Apps on Moto 360 for Debug Purposes

Tags: android, wear-os, moto-360

I'm trying to write a wearable app with custom layout notifications, however my emulator is not displaying custom wearable notifications properly. (I just get a card with a black box... it even happens on the sample app notifications).

I have a Moto 360 but since it doesn't have a USB port, I don't know how to deploy a debugable app on there using Android Studio.

Any thoughts? (Trying to not create and package and app / publish to the store to debug as that would be a huge waste of time if there is a way to directly package apps and ship them to the moto 360).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can deploy your app on your smartphone connected via BT to your 360.
Follow this link
[Android Wear BT debugging](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html)

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately developer docs are utterly confusing in this regard.  They say: "Connect the wearable to your machine through USB, so you can install apps directly to it as you develop."  Right on this page: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Comment: The docs have been updated:
"Note: If you can not connect your wearable to your machine via USB, follow the directions on Debugging over Bluetooth."